# How to set nested state in vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a very complicated state in my application like:

```
state: {
  formFieldList: [
    {
      name: 'RadioGroup',
      schema: {
       edit:true,
       label:"Radios",
       name:"Radios",
       type:"radios",
       values: [
         {
           labelName: 'default',
           value: 'default',
         }
         {
           labelName: 'default2',
           value: 'default',
         }
       ]
     },
     {
      name: 'RadioGroup1',
      schema: {
       edit:true,
       label:"Radios1",
       name:"Radios1",
       type:"radios1",
       values: [
         {
           labelName: 'default',
           value: 'default',
         }
         {
           labelName: 'default2',
           value: 'default',
         }
       ]
     },
   },
 ],
}
```

As Vuejs Array Changing Caveats, I use Vue.set in my mutation.When I set **values** array in one **fieldList** item,It will update all **RadioGroup** values.

```
updateOptionValue(state, { index, optionIndex, value }) {
  let values = state.formFieldList[index].schema.values;
  let labelName = values[optionIndex].labelName;
  Vue.set(values, optionIndex, {
    labelName,
    value,
  });
}
```

How can I handle nested array update?
Here's my simple demo on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/w6nq81l808

As I add two radiogrouops to the red area(click radiogroup twice), and edit the two radiosgroups simultaneously, the value will change in the same time.

Comment: I dont see why `Vue.set(state.formFieldList[index].schema.values, optionIndex, value)` wouldn't work.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter If don't use Vue set,it will not detact array changing,https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, I had created a demo on codesanbox, the mutaion updateOptionLabel in Store was not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign state attribute to new object to make it reactive:

```
updateOptionValue(state, { index, optionIndex, value }) {
  let values = state.formFieldList[index].schema.values;
  let labelName = values[optionIndex].labelName;
  values[optionIndex] = {
    value,
    labelName
  }
  state.formFieldList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.formFieldList)) // assign new object
}
```

Comment: I changed my mutation code as you said,it almost work.But when I input first character, It will update both values in my formFieldList array,https://codesandbox.io/s/w6nq81l808